# Efficient way to read file larger than memory in R

Tags: r, data.table, ff

This reference https://www.r-bloggers.com/efficiency-of-importing-large-csv-files-in-r/ compares reading a file using fread versus ffdf. I am currently trying to read a csv file that is abour 60GB while my memory available on RAM is 16GB. It takes about 2 hours to do so. Would you recommend a faster way?

Comment: did you consider splitting the csv file into multiple files?

Comment: I have not tried that yet, would you suggest splitting the csv files and then reading them separately? I would assume that ffdf would do the same, but faster wouldnt it? since i specify under next.rows the number of rows I want to read in a chunkwise fashion

Comment: The main question is whether you really, really need all the data in that file in one go. Because if not, or if you can process the data line wise, then there is no need of loading it all in one go and other options open up. For example, you can read in line by line, process each line; you can read in by chunks, process each chunk etc.

Answer (score 1):

`bigmemory` works in this situation.

```r
library(bigmemory)
library(biganalytics)
x <- read.big.matrix("airline.csv", type="integer", header=TRUE,
                     backingfile="airline.bin",
                     descriptorfile="airline.desc",
                     extraCols="Age")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Data.Table Package.

Seems to be faster Function Fread.

Function:

```
"File Name"<- fread("Uploadfile.txt", header =  TRUE, colClasses = "character")
```

Comment: Unlikely to help, as the low speed probably results from the fact that the file is too large for the memory and needs to be cached.

Answer (score 0):

disk.frame can chunk the file into smaller parts, uses fst format and you can use data.table or dplyr syntax.

install.packages("disk.frame")

see here for more info: [https://diskframe.com/#:~:text=frame%7D%20is%20an%20R%20package,to%20be%20processed%20by%20R](https://diskframe.com/#:%7E:text=frame%7D%20is%20an%20R%20package,to%20be%20processed%20by%20R).